# List of tuples with different size and type in swift

Tags: swift, list, tuples

I wanna make a list of tuples in Swift that fits this two conditions:

```
1 - the type of the tuples can be different

2 - the size of the tuples can be different
```

This is an example of the list I wanna be able to make:

```
let list = [
    (1, 2, 3),
    ("abc", 5),
    (1, "hello", 3.5, "stack overflow")
]
```

Basically, the sizes and types are different (but the types will be only Int, Float and String).

Is it possible to create something like this?

When I try, it says "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context".

PS: if its possible with list of lists, how can I make a lista of different kinds of type?

Thank you!

Comment: Tuples are designed for temporary groups of related data, not for permanent storage – you should consider using a 2D array instead. Although what's the actual use case of this?

Comment: every element of the list will be a input for one of 5 different types of event within the program, so there will be 5 types of tuples, but i wanted them all inside a single list to make things easier.
Thanks for the tip, but I dont know how I can adapt 2D array with different types yet

Comment: Are the contents of the each tuple related (i.e they represent a similar concept), or do they just represent different 'properties' of each event? If you could clarify the post with a concrete example, that'd be great.

Comment: yeah.. every event has a type and a number. the other elements differ

Comment: Yeah, perhaps there's a better way of representing this, as structs or a composition of structs.

Comment: thanks for the help guys! I'll use a struct.. its the best choice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a job for a struct.

Since there are 5 different permutations of your data, you can create 5 structs, each of which to conform to a common protocol. You can then make your array hold a list of those structs by their more general protocol type.